# Obtener un formato de fecha especifico en PHP

Tags: php

Cómo puedo obtener este formato de fecha ya que la necesito usar para un reporte en FPDF

> Venezuela, 8 de Diciembre del 2016

Comment: Como recibes ésta información? Puedes mostrar el código?

Comment: Existen cientos de formas para hacerlo, ¿Hay algún método en particular que andes aplicando? Si es así, por favor, edita la pregunta con tu código para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: como lo puso el amigo Garrizano me ha sevido era exactamenge lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
$hoy = date("\V\\e\\n\\e\z\u\\e\l\a\, j \d\\e F \d\\e\l Y");
```

Comment: gracias funciono perfectamnte

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil imprimir la palabra Venezuela fuera de la función `date()`?

Comment: ok pudiera ser buena idea